# Eclipse error when trying to open Eclipse Marketplace: Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace Cannot install remote marketplace locations

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to install some dependencies on my Eclipse Oxygen when I suddenly hit this error. The full error message is:

```
Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Cannot complete request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: Invalid response content: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".
Cannot complete request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: Invalid response content: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".
Invalid response content: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".
The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".
Received response begins with:

1: <!DOCTYPE html>
2: 
3: <html lang="en">

Cannot complete request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: Invalid response content: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".
Invalid response content: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".
The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".
Received response begins with:

1: <!DOCTYPE html>
2: 
3: <html lang="en">
```

It was fine before. I started to see this error after I installed IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5x Developer Tools for Oxygen. I am very new to Eclipse so I'm not sure how to debug this.

Yes I have internet and I have no antivirus installed (it's running in a CentOS VM). I also have tried resetting the network connection settings to default but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api*` to the Proxy Bypass settings solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

Tried everything possible on the internet! Failed.
The issue is with our network only. Please check if you have any content filtering enabled on your network, URL blocker/filter, security-enabled that blocks certain keywords in URLs.
For me, It was Content Filtering enabled on my WiFi Router, which was blocking certain URLs.